# Ajax - on mouseover send request to controller and render results into a div

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

im working on a project in mvc and what i try to do is to use a Ajax function on mouseover to get 
information from my database.

i have add a controller action and a view to render the results.

but nothing work.

i have try a lot of things but i can´t understand where is the problem because nothing happend.

Its the first time for me to use a ajax function , so im a newbie ..

Hope that everyone can give me a hand with this.

here is my code:

**Ajax:**

```
 $("#mybutton").mouseover(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action(“MyAction”,”MyController”)", 
            success: function (result) {
                $("#InformationBox").html(result); /*<--div id where the results are showing*/
            }
        });
    });
```

**MainView:**

```
<form action="@Url.Action("MyPostAction", "MyController")" method="post">
                      <button type="submit" name="submit" id="mybutton">
                      </button>                     
                      <input type="hidden" name="Id_Hidden" value="1" id="AjaxSendId"/>
                  </form>
```

**Controller:**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult PartialViewExample(FormCollection formcollection) 
        {
            var id_option = formcollection["Id_Hidden"];

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            cn.Open();
            sb.AppendLine("Select Id From Table1 ");
            sb.AppendLine("WHERE Id='" + id_option + "'");

            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), cn).ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(1))
                {
                    object value = sqlDataReader[1];
                    infolist(new Table1()
                    {
                        Name = value.ToString(),
                    });
                }
            }

            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
            sqlDataReader.Dispose();

            ViewBag.Options = infolist

            return View("HintExampleView_Layout");
    }
```

**HintExampleView_Layout (render results but showing in the MainView):**

```
<div id="InformationBox">
    @foreach (var p in ViewBag.Options)
    {
        @p.Step2Name
        @p.IconHover 
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Why not create a model which contains a list of options then parse the model to the view using return View("HintExampleView_Layout", myModel); This is much better than using ViewBag

Comment: Could you post a full stack trace for your error?

Comment: Also worth noting that your quotes are curved ” and not straight " try and update the code in your JavaScript and see if that solves the problem

Comment: @AshleyMedway:  yes you are right... this solved my problem of url action... but still nothing happend

Comment: To help debug try putting an alert("TEST") before your ajax call to see if the mouseover event is ever being ran.

Comment: i have done what you said.. the mouseover event do nothing...

Comment: wrap your jQuery in a $(document).ready(function { }); See -    http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I have added an answer which may help

Answer (score 1):

**MainView:**

```
<form action="@Url.Action("PartialViewExample", "MyController")" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="mybutton">
    </button>                     
    <input type="hidden" name="Id_Hidden" value="1" id="AjaxSendId"/>
</form>
<div id="InformationBox">&nbsp;</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
return PartialView("HintExampleView_Layout");
```

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function {     
    $("#mybutton").mouseover(function () {
        alert("Mouseover Test"); /* <- Remove me if working */
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")", 
            success: function (result) {
                $("#InformationBox").html(result); /*<--div id where the results are showing*/
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: but can´t get any information from my controller.. i have set a breakpoint to the action to see if the ajax function call it but no.. any idea??

Comment: You can't debug JavaScript in visual studio unfortunately, put a break point at the start of your controller where this line is "var id_option = formcollection["Id_Hidden"];" also change return View to return PartialView

Comment: i have updated my code with yours, but still nothing happend... i think he is not access the action in the controller

Comment: make sure that "MyAction" is the name of your action and "MyController" is the name of your controller for example @Url.Action("Index","Home")

Answer (score 0):

humm your URL is not good (if you are not in the cshtml file), you are in client side don't forget :

```
 $("#mybutton").mouseover(function () {
        $.ajax({
            **url: "@Url.Action(“MyAction”,”MyController”)",** 
            success: function (result) {
                $("#InformationBox").html(result); /*<--div id where the results are showing*/
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your post rad... i have try this before and my problem it has an error in the url action, the error is ")" expected.. but i don´t know why because i have verify all open and close "()"